# Converting to SquashFS for BerryBoot

Tags: raspbian, image, bash, berryboot

I have been following an online course on operating system development, named [baking pi](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/).I have successfully followed 'OK01'
As I don't have 2 SD cards, and I find it fiddly to swap operating systems on my SD cards, I decided to use the berryboot boot loader. There are a list of commands on [page on the berryboot website](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot/adding_custom_distributions) to convert an normal raspberry pi operating system image to a SquashFS image that berryboot can use. Upon executing the first executing the first command `sudo kpartx -av kernel.img`, it gave me an error:

```
read error, sector 0
llseek error
llseek error
llseek error
```

Note: everything was done in bash on raspbian (including `kpartx`)